# Выдает ошибку что выхожу за пределы массива, хотя проверяю это в цикле

Tags: java

Выдает ошибку что выхожу за пределы массива, хотя проверяю это в цикле. Тем не менее через раз, выводит ошибку.

```
package supreme;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
            menu();
    }
    public static void menu() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        System.out.print("1.Crypt\n2.Uncrypt\n3.Exit\nPlease make your choice: ");
        switch(choice = in.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your string which will be crypted: ");
                String line = in.next();
                byte[] crypting = line.getBytes();
                System.out.println("Please enter your password(it can be any number): ");
                String temp = in.next();
                char [] password = temp.toCharArray();
                for ( int i = 0; i <crypting.length; i ++ ) {
                    System.out.println("Element " + i +" is: " +  crypting[i]);
                }
                int counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < crypting.length; i++) {
                    if(counter == crypting.length) counter = 0;

                    if((password[counter] == '1') && (password[counter+1] == '0')) {
                        crypting[i] = (byte)(crypting[i] << 1);
                    }
                    if(password[counter] == '0' && password[counter+1] == '1') {
                        crypting[i] = (byte)(crypting[i] >> 1);
                    }
                    if(password[counter] == '1' && password[counter+1] == '1') {
                        crypting[i] = (byte)(~crypting[i]);
                    }
                    counter+=2;
                    System.out.println(counter);
                }

                System.out.println("After crypt!");
                for( int i = 0; i <crypting.length; i ++ ) {
                    System.out.println("Element " + i +" is: " +  crypting[i]);
                }
                String crypted = new String(crypting);
                System.out.println(crypted);
                byte [] sss = crypted.getBytes();
                for(int i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(sss[i]);

                }
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Please, choose one of the possible variants:");
                menu();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (counter >= password.length - 2) counter = 0;
```